# Is there a way to extract data from the value of a key from list of dictionary in the list form using python

Tags: python

I'm trying to extract data from following HTML code:

```
"profile"[{"emp_id":"ABC0001","emp_info":{"age":"35yrs","gender":"Male","dob":"24jan1988","address":"xyz"},"emgy_contact":"abcd_1223456"}]
```

using the following codes:

```
for item in data['profile']:
    for key, val in item.items():
        print(f'{key}: {val}')
```

got this result:

```
emp_id: ABC0001
emp_info: {"age":"35yrs","gender":"Male","dob":"24jan1988","address":"xyz"},"emgy_contact":"abcd_1223456"}
```

What i'm looing for is this result:

```
emp_id: ABC0001
emp_info: 
age: 35yrs
gender: Male
dob: 24jan1988
address: xyz
emgy_contact:abcd_1223456
```

can anyone here help me out, Thank you

Comment: What is the first line supposed to mean? You can't assign to a string literal. Did you mean `data["profile"]=`?

Comment: `SyntaxError: cannot assign to literal here. Maybe you meant '==' instead of '='?`

Comment: It is just sample data (madeup). sorry abt tht. there is no '=' there.  what i'm try to do is get a an output as show above. also feel free to edit the sample data. Thank you

Comment: @skywalker The problem isn't the data. The problem is the `"profile"` on the left of the `=`. This isn't valid python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another nested loop when the value is a nested dictionary.

```
for item in data['profile']:
    for key, value in item.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            for key1, value1 in value.items():
                print(f'{key1}: {value1}')
        else:
            print(f'{key}: {value}')
    print()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you quick respones. And your codes are perfectly inline with mine which requires minimal edits on my end.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping over the `key, val` at the top level, you should loop over `item['emp_info']`:

```
for item in data['profile']:
    print(f'emp_id: {item['emp_id']}
    for key, val in item['emp_info'].items():
        print(f'    {key}: {val}')
```

Answer (score 0):

To handle any maonut of nested things, I'd suggest a recursive method that handles specific cases like `dict` or `list` as they should

```
def recur_print(values):
    if isinstance(values, list):
        for item in values:
            recur_print(item)
    elif isinstance(values, dict):
        for key, value in values.items():
            if not isinstance(value, (list, dict)):
                print(f"{key}: {value}")
            else:
                print(f"{key}:")
                recur_print(value)
    else:
        print(values)

data = {
    "profile": [
        {"emp_id": "ABC0001", "emp_info": {"age": "35yrs", "gender": "Male", "dob": "24jan1988", "address": "xyz"},
         "emgy_contact": "abcd_1223456"},
        {"emp_id": "ABC0002", "emp_info": {"age": "38yrs", "gender": "Male", "dob": "24jan1988", "address": "xyz"},
         "emgy_contact": "abcd_1223456"}
    ]
}

recur_print(data["profile"])
```

```
emp_id: ABC0001
emp_info:
age: 35yrs
gender: Male
dob: 24jan1988
address: xyz
emgy_contact: abcd_1223456
emp_id: ABC0002
emp_info:
age: 38yrs
gender: Male
dob: 24jan1988
address: xyz
emgy_contact: abcd_1223456
```