# how to extract data from a nested dictionary of a key in python

Tags: python

I'm new to coding.. Any help is appericated Thank you
So following the code that I'm tring to extract

```
"defaultKit": {
    "options": {
        "size": "Med/32",
        "color": "blue/green"
    },
    "part": "MK78Z62"
}
```

This is output i'm looking for

size: Med/32

color: blue/green

part: MK78Z62

And here is what i have so far

```html
data2 = json.loads(data2)
for item in data2['defaultKit']:
    for key, value in items.items():
        print(f'{key1}: {value1}')
```

i'm getting this error:

```
for key, value in item.items():
                      ^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Comment: The error message `for key, value in item.items()` does not match the code `for key, value in items.items():`  (The first one has `item.`, and the second has `items.`).  When you post code, always cut-and-paste.  Don't retype it by hand, because small errors like this always creep in.

Comment: There are no repetitive parts in your data structure. Therefore, a loop makes no sense

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to extract data from the value of a key from list of dictionary in the list form using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77204545/is-there-a-way-to-extract-data-from-the-value-of-a-key-from-list-of-dictionary-i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need nested conditions to check whether your value is a dictionary or not.

Also your dictionary `data2` needs `{}`

```
data2 = {"defaultKit":{"options":{"size":"Med/32","color":"blue/green"},"part":"MK78Z62"}}
```

---

```
for key, value in data2.items():
    if isinstance(value, dict) :
        for key1, value1 in value.items():
            if isinstance(value1, dict) :
                for key2, value2 in value1.items():
                    print(f'{key2}: {value2}')
            else:        
                print(f'{key1}: {value1}')
                
    else:
        print(f'{key}: {value}')

#output

size: Med/32
color: blue/green
part: MK78Z62
```

Comment: In the original code, there is comma instead of { before the "defaultKit" and it is preceeded by another key like this ----->

Key1{ }, {Key2{ },"defaultKit": {
    "options": {
        "size": "Med/32",
        "color": "blue/green"
    },
    "part": "MK78Z62"
}

Comment: I figured it out. I made this change

for key, value in data2['defaultKit'].items():

Thank you very much for your help. Really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the error because iterating over a dictionary like this:

```
for item in data2['defaultKit']
```

gives you **just the keys**, as string values.  So on the first loop iteration, `item` is the string "options".

Since you already know the exact items you want to print, you don't need a loop at all.  Just print them directly.

```
print('size:', data2['defaultKit']['options']['size'])
print('color:', data2['defaultKit']['options']['color'])
print('part:', data2['defaultKit']['part'])
```

(Using a loop might have been more efficient, **if** the things you wanted to print were all at the same level within the dict.  But they're not -- two of them are inside the "options" subdictionary, but the third one isn't.)

Comment: Thank you very much for this beautiful explanation. It give me a clear idea and better understanding.

Comment: @skywalker You can thank me by clicking the green checkmark, which will accept this as a good answer.

Comment: I'm looking for different approach since i'm  going to use it to a larger data set where giving in print command for every desired item might be hectic. I shall wait i see if any other ideas comes around. :)

Comment: @skywalker Fair enough.  Surely I deserve at least an upvote (click on the up arrow)?

Answer (score 0):

directly iterating over the dictionary data2["defaultKit"] results in just the keys being returned.   You probably want to go directly to the options with data2["defaultKit"]["options"] and iterate over its .items() result.